# Online backup: Backup a partition while editing some files in it

Tags: backup

Backing up a partition takes long. Is it possible for me to edit a few files in that partition, while backing up the partition, so that the backup is still up to date, i.e. the same as the partition at the time when the backup finishes? Thanks.

Comment: if the former is impossible, can the latter be possible?

Comment: I don't know which program to use yet. The backup is for my data. Bit by bit and file by file are both okay as long as they can allow me to edit some files in the partition at the same time of backup.

Comment: I hope I can edit some files during bakcup, because I don't want to be idle myself. but it is not a must. I like to know the best or good solutions for both cases: if I edit and if I don't edit some files in the partition during backup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i.e. the same as the partition at the time when the backup finishes?

No, you can't get a consistent backup that is fully up to date at the *end*, but you can get a consistent backup that represents the state of the disk at the *start* by using an LVM snapshot.  You create a snapshot with `lvcreate -s`, and that gets you a new device whose contents appear to be the state of the original volume at the time you created the snapshot, while you continue to modify the original volume.  Then you can backup the snapshot without worrying that the backup will contain a mix of data from before and during the backup.  When you're done with the backup, you delete the snapshot.

This of course, requires that you installed the system originally using lvm and have some free space in your physical volume(s) to create the snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

**Online backup of whole partitions is a terrible idea**

Backing up a partition can take a long time. Internet connection can break. If that happens when you are halfway through the online backup, you will be left with a huge file of garbage.

A partition to be backed up, should be unmounted. If you mount the partition and fiddle with it, you will most likely end up with a huge file of garbage.

Think about backing up your the files in your `/home` folder rather than backing up a whole partition.

Use a backup software. There is a default one installed in Ubuntu. Set it up to backup often. Backup software are designed to do incremental backup. If you edit some files then the next time it backs up, it will only backup those files, and not everything else. You can backup every ten minutes, or every minute, or every hour.

Backup to an external hard drive. Or another computer connected to your home network.

Incremental backup alone doesn't solve the problem since if you modify the file or files during the backup, the backup can still grab a half modified file or set of files. This is particularly true if you are in the business of video editing.

Of course, since it does take much less time than a full backup, it may be acceptable to make sure you aren't updating any files for the duration of the incremental backup.

**For desktops:** I recommend that you schedule full backup at late night or whenever you are likely to sleep. Keep your desktop on at night so that it can make backups without human interruptions.

**For laptops:** I recommend that you backup after you are done working for the day. You may also want to backup and charge your laptop at the same time.

---

For the ease of use I suggest the GUI **Backup** that comes pre-installed. If you want a command line solution, you don't have to look farther than `rsync` and `cron` (or `anacron`).

[`rsync`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync) is a very powerful command line tool you can use in a script with many options. One of those options backs up (copies) only files that have changed. You will need two scripts, one for full backup and one for incremental one. Both will use `rsync` with different options.

[`cron` and `anacron`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) are powerful tools to automate the backup script, so that it gets executed at fixed interval.

[Ubuntu's official documentation on the topic of backup is pretty good.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. Is there command line tools for incremental backup which you recommend?

Comment: @Tim, incremental backup alone doesn't solve the problem since if you modify the file or files during the backup, the backup can still grab a half modified file or set of files.  Of course, since it does take much less time than a full backup, it may be acceptable to make sure you aren't updating any files for the duration of the incremental backup.